# How do I populate a Vaadin 12.0.4 Grid with data/fields from a PostgreSQL 10.5 table or view?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, mybatis, vaadin12

I know there are dozens of tutorials for how to do this across just as many websites, but this is my first time trying to connect a database table to a UI, so when the version of Spring Boot/MyBatis/Vaadin, for example, are different than the one I'm working with, or they use JPA or JDBC instead of MyBatis, I have no idea how to change it to work with my specific situation.

When people say "it's no different than any other method of doing it with " that doesn't help AT ALL, since, as I stated earlier, I've never done it before. Annotations and classes in the code examples of a tutorial get removed and deprecated with every new version with no clear explanation of how to change it to work with the newer version. I've been researching the various APIs (Spring Boot, Vaadin, MyBatis) for about a month and have a vague understanding of what each one does but not how they work together to achieve the desired result of making a UI for a database. I'm just getting really frustrated at how a single deprecated annotation or class in a tutorial can bring the whole thing crashing down. I know that was long-winded but I just wanted you all to understand where I'm coming from. I'm not particularly attached to any single API, just whatever is easiest.

My current dependencies are:

`- Maven : 4.0.0
 - Spring Boot: 2.1.2.RELEASE
 - Vaadin: 12.0.4
 - MyBatis Spring Boot Starter: 2.0.0`

I got the starter package from Spring Initializr and added the MyBatis dependency later.

I have a PostgreSQL 10.5 database with 17 tables that will eventually be a UI for a store manager to use for things like looking at received inventory shipments, the hours an employee worked, and other tasks.

My database is named 'store', user: 'store', password: 'store' (if it matters).

For example, these are a few of my tables:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS supplier (
    id          SERIAL,
    brand       VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
    phone       VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
    address     VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_supplier PRIMARY KEY (id)
);`

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shipment (
    id          SERIAL,
    shipdate    DATE            NOT NULL,
    shiptime    TIME            NOT NULL,
    status      VARCHAR(10)     DEFAULT 'arrived' NOT NULL,
    sid         INT             NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_shipment PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_shipment_supplier FOREIGN KEY (sid)
        REFERENCES supplier(id)
);`

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shipmentcontains (
    shipid      INT             NOT NULL,
    iid         INT             NOT NULL,
    quantity    INT             NOT NULL,
    price       DEC(6,2)        NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_shipmentcontains PRIMARY KEY (shipid, iid),
    CONSTRAINT fk_shipmentcontains_shipment FOREIGN KEY (shipid)
        REFERENCES shipment(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_shipmentcontains_item FOREIGN KEY (iid)
        REFERENCES item(id)
);`

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item (
    id          SERIAL,
    itemtype    VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL,
    itemsize    VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL,
    price       DEC(5,2)        NOT NULL,
    sid         INT             NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_item PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_item_supplier FOREIGN KEY (sid)
        REFERENCES supplier(id)
);`

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (
    id          SERIAL,
    lastname    VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    firstname   VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    hourlywage  DEC(4,2),
    manager     BOOLEAN         DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_employee PRIMARY KEY (id)
);`

If someone can give me a code example of how to just get one of those to show in a Grid, I'm sure I can figure out how to do the rest of it. I have the connection details in my `application.properties` file, but I've seen that with newer versions of MyBatis this isn't needed and annotations such as `@Update` can be used on the SQL statements to replace that. Also, in plain English, what the heck is a Spring Bean? I hope that wasn't too long..or not long enough.

EDIT: Current version of Vaadin 12 is 12.0.4

Comment: I'm sorry to say to say that but your question is an off-topic on SO. First, of all it is very broad. The question should be about some specific problem. Secondly, it doesn't show your research effort. You need to improve it. One way would be to describe what approach you tried and what does not work. Like if you tried some example that is based on the old version of say vaadin then you might get it working first (in the old version) and then search and ask if there's no answer already a specific question `What is a way to implement deprecated feature X of vaadin version Y in newer version Z?`

Comment: This is a website where people ask programming questions and that was a programming question. I did ask a specific question, it was in the title and at the end, you just weren't paying attention. If I showed everything that I've tried that didn't work, it would be so long nobody would read it. Things I've tried from tutorials using older versions are irrelevant since all that's necessary is to show what works currently. I don't see how it's hard for someone with sufficient skill to to give an example of what I've asked. Or maybe you've forgotten what being a novice programmer is like.

Comment: yes it's quite broad but IMO the op showed research effort and explained why that research was fruitless. Yes, all the info can be gathered by visiting the right sites and blogs and tutorials, but you need to know exactly what you're googling for, which does not seem to be the case for op. I don't care if I get downvotes but I gladly posted an answer. Hope it helps

Comment: @KevinPalembas I can understand your frustration. My comment intent was not to offend but to help you improve the question so that you can get the answer. While the title is rather specific, the information about what you tried is not very helpful. Especially the question is missing the information what specifically does not work. As an example you are saying that annotations are removed/deprecated in general but no specific one is mentioned.

Comment: I understand. I've done vector calculus and intermediate physics, but there's nothing like programming to make ya feel stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking quite a lot, so I will try to touch everything a little and nothing too detailed. I hope this helps you getting the ball rolling.

First off, you will need a java class with all fields that you have in the supplier table, annotated with `@Entity`. The `@Table` annotation lets you define the Db table name, and it is not necessary if the table is called the same as the class (case insensitive):

```
@Entity                        // javax.persistence
@Table(name = "supplier")      // javax.persistence
public class Supplier {

    @Id                        // javax.persistence
    private Long id;

    private String brand;
    private String phone;
    private String address;

    public Supplier(){

    }

    // public getters and setters for all fields
    // omitted for brevity
}
```

Now that you have a class for your table, you can start with creating a Vaadin Grid for it. This can be done the easiest with `Grid<Supplier> supplierGrid = new Grid<Supplier>(Supplier.class);`.

Now to fill the grid with items (suppliers). This is done with `supplierGrid.setItems(allSuppliers);`. But where do `allSuppliers` come from you ask?

They can be fetched using a [Repository](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories). Because the repository will be annotated with `@Repository`, its a spring component that can be *automatically generated* by spring and can be [Injected/Autowired](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire) (i.e. in your view) using `@Inject`/`@Autowired`.
Then you simply call `List<Supplier> allSuppliers = supplierRepository.findAll()` and you have a list of all suppliers from your DB, that you now can put into the grid with the aforementioned `supplierGrid.setItems(allSuppliers);`

Any class where an instance of it can be injected by spring is a spring-bean, this includes classes annotated with either @Component, @Serivce or @Repository. Entities like Supplier can not automatically be injected by Spring, unless you define this is your @Configuration class:

```
/* Do this only if you want to inject a Supplier somewhere. */
@Bean
public Supplier supplier(){
    /* define here how a default Supplier should look like */
    return new Supplier();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples and explanations. it's exactly what I was looking for. I'll try this on the Supplier table and see if I have any problems. The only thing I foresee going wrong is the @Entity annotation. Whenever I've used it before IntelliJ colors it red and says `Cannot resolve symbol 'Entity'`..which it just did again when I put it in my StoreuiApplication class, which is annotated with @SpringBootApplication. Should MainView be inside that class or it's own class, btw?

Comment: There are many little things like that that I left out, since your question was so broad. For detailed problems like `Cannot resolve symbol 'Entity'` I think you have now more information than before and should be able to search the solution on your own (I don't know either, probably missing dependencies). And no, let MainView be a standalone class. I am more a Vaadin guy than a Spring chap, I'm not very knowledgeable in that part I'm afraid. I already leaned outside my comfort zone with all these explanations of spring stuff

Comment: I really appreciate it. I'm planning to have it eventually where a manager end user could select a month from a combo box and it would show all the Shipments, maybe filtered by Supplier, that the store received in that month (by date, not ID). Then they could click on a shipment and it would show everything that was in that shipment. and that's just one of a few..uh views, I guess you'd call it? that will make up the UI. So the Repository you mentioned is what Vaadin would consider a DataProvider? I'm just confused how the data actually gets from the database into the Grid.

Comment: No a vaadin dataprovider is nothing of that sort, and was used more in older vaadin versions. You can still set dataproviders for a grid instead of `grid.setItems()` and you can do a little more configuration / filtering when you use a dataprovider. just use `setItems()` for now until you have your grids done and working. As I mentioned, the data is fetched from the DB by a `@Repository`. That repository (or a `@Service` which in turn has the repository injected) can be injected in your view. Through that you can load your entities from DB and then put it into the grid

Comment: I'm getting the same error for setItems that I was getting before for @Entity. The dependency for setItems should already exist since Grid is in my project. It should be one of the methods inherited from HasDataProvider. maybe something got moved in Vaadin 12 and they forgot to update the API docs.

Comment: Actually it looks like I have to implement an interface like binderHasDataProvider before it can use setItems. I was looking at BackEndDataProvider. I keep seeing everywhere in the tutorials that they use something called a Binder to connect the Java table class to the database tables. But some are too old to be for even Vaadin 10.

Comment: The Binder is **not** used for tables/grids. it's used to bind input fields with values of an object of yours, like a supplier. As for the rest, it's really not easy to understand what you mean, let alone answer appropriately. Would you mind making new posts for any question that you still have?

Comment: ohh that makes a lot more sense. Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Happy to help. I'm also glad that Alejandro from the official vaadin team has offered to chat with you real time, this is gonna be really valuable help! you can do it, don't give up

Comment: so he heard about me looking far and wide for answers? lol He was a lot of help :)

Comment: During the video chat I had with Alejandro, he told me the @Entity tag was indicative of a JPA approach for connecting the database tables (aka business objects, as you might see it on some websites). If you want to use MyBatis for that instead, as I was going for initially, an example of how to do that with a Company table in a PostgreSQL database can be found [here](https://github.com/alejandro-du/postgres-vaadin-10-mybatis-demo). If you want to type it instead of copying and pasting, you should at least make sure you have all the same dependencies as the pom.xml in the Git project.